# Error en un programa para almacenar palabras

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy queriendo crear un programa el cual analice las palabras que hay en un texto y luego cuente cuantas palabras distintas hay, pero estoy teniendo un problema. por algún motivo, algunas palabras no me las considera, es decir, que al analizar, las interpreta como repetidas, siendo que nunca se las habia agregado antes.

Consideren que estoy empezando en `python`, si existe alguna manera mas sencilla de hacer esto o alguna forma de mejorar en mi código se los agradecería.

```
text = input("escribe tu texto: \n")
counter=0
words=[]
letters=[]
letters.append([])
for i in text:
    if i==" ":
        counter+=1
        words.append(returned)
        letters.append([])
        print(words[len(words)-1])
        continue
    elif (i=="," or i=="." or i=="(" or i==")" or i=="?" or i=="¿" or i=="¡" or i=="!"): 
        counter+=1
        letters.append([])
        continue
    letters[counter].append(i)
    returned="".join(letters[counter])
    if words.count(returned)!=0:
        words.pop(len(words)-1)
print(words)
```

Comment: Lucho K, te recomiendo esta lectura: https://www.nltk.org/. Es un módulo que se especializa en análisis de texto. Quizás pueda darte un enfoque más potente sobre lo que necesitas.

Comment: agradezco tu aporte, pero estoy haciendo este programa para poner a prueba mis conocimientos en python, es a modo de practica para entender las listas, bucles for, condicionales, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Qué intentas hacer

Dices que tu intención era contar cuántas palabras diferentes hay. Inicialmente pensé que se trataba de generar como resultado una lista de palabras diferentes *junto con la cuenta de cuántas veces aparece cada una*, ya que hablabas de "contar". Pero lo que en realidad intentas generar es una lista con las palabras distintas.

Por tanto podríamos decir que lo que haces es "eliminar palabras repetidas" y dejar sólo una de cada.

### Qué no funciona

Dices que algunas palabras no las procesa. Uno de estos casos sería el de la última palabra de la frase. La razón de que no te procese la última palabra es que, tal como tienes el código, sólo procesa la palabra anterior cuando encuentra un espacio. La última palabra no va seguida de espacio y por eso no la "ves".

Hay más errores de lógica, pues el `words.pop()` que usas, supongo que con la intención de eliminar una palabra si ha aparecido repetida, en realidad elimina la última palabra que hayas insertado, esté repetida o no. Así que si el usuario por ejemplo escribe "uno dos tres dos cuatro cinco", al encontrarse el segundo "dos", se elimina la última insertada, que era "tres" (y encima se inserta "dos"). Ya que además la última ("cinco") no se procesa, el resultado final es la lista `["una", "dos", "dos", "cuatro"]`, incorrecta.

### Crítica al código

El código es muy complejo. Innecesariamente complejo. Aparentemente parece que lo que quieres hacer es procesar el texto "letra a letra" e ir acumulando esas letras en la variable `letters`, para formar con ellas palabras cada vez que detectes un espacio. Después, procesar las palabras añadiéndolas a otra lista, y según cierta condición que no acabo de comprender (pero no funciona bien), eliminar la última palabra de la lista.

Todo esto mediante unas estructuras de datos que tampoco comprendo, pues la lista `letters` contiene dentro incialmente otra lista vacía cuya función se me escapa.

### Una versión más simple

Python tiene el método `.split()` aplicable a cadenas, que te divide un texto en sub-cadenas usando para dividir los puntos donde aparecen espacios, o secuencias de espacios. Por ejemplo:

```
>>> txt = "uno dos tres     dos cuatro   cinco"
>>> txt.split()
['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'dos', 'cuatro', 'cinco']
```

Esto hace mucho más sencillo el procesado. Basta iterar sobre esta lista e ir añadiendo a otra todas las palabras *que no estén ya* en esa otra. Es muy sencillo verificar si ya había palabras en otra lista, mediante el operador `in`.

Usando estas ideas:

```
text = input("escribe tu texto: \n")

words = []
for word in text.split():
    if word not in words:
        words.append(word)
print(words)
```

Lo único que no hace este código es "saltarse" los signos de puntuación. No tengo claro si tu código original se los saltaba, o los consideraba también como un separador de palabras. Creo que la forma más simple de añadir esa funcionalidad sería cambiarlos por espacios, justo después de leer el texto. Para ello que puedes usar expresiones regulares, o si prefieres no usarlas, puede hacerse también mediante una comprensión de listas como la siguiente:

```
punct_signs = [".", ",", "?", "¿", "!", "¡", "(", ")" ]
text = "".join(letter if letter not in punct_signs else " "
               for letter in text)
```

o, si prefieres una sintaxis más convencional:

```
punct_signs = [".", ",", "?", "¿", "!", "¡", "(", ")" ]
aux = []
for letter in text:
    if letter in punct_signs:
        aux.append(" ")
    else:
        aux.append(letter)
text = "".join(aux)
```

### Opción "avanzada"

Python tiene el tipo de dato `set()`, que es como una lista pero sin orden y que sólo guarda elementos diferentes (si intentas añadir a un `set()` un elemento que ya estaba, simplemente no se añadirá).

Puedes construir un `set()` pasándole una lista, y automáticamente eliminará los duplicados. El `set()` resultante puedes volver a convertirlo en lista con `list()`, si fuera necesario.

Usando esto, la funcionalidad que buscas se reduce a estas cuatro líneas:

```
text = input("escribe tu texto: \n")
punct_signs = [".", ",", "?", "¿", "!", "¡", "(", ")" ]
text = "".join(letter if letter not in punct_signs else " " for letter in text)

words = set(text.split())
print(words)
```

Y si lo que querías era obtener un contador de cuántas veces se repite cada palabra, python también te da uno ya hecho en el módulo `collections`, por lo que el código en este caso sería así:

```
from collections import Counter

text = input("escribe tu texto: \n")
punct_signs = [".", ",", "?", "¿", "!", "¡", "(", ")" ]
text = "".join(letter if letter not in punct_signs else " " for letter in text)

words = Counter(text.split())
print(words)
```

Si por ejemplo introduces "uno dos tres dos tres cuatro", la salida sería `{'dos': 2, 'tres': 2, 'uno': 1, 'cuatro': 1}`

Comment: muchisimas gracias, la verdad es que como recien empiezo en esto de la programacion en python no conozco muchos elementos que tiene, la verdad que simplificar todo el codigo a solo 6 lineas es impresionante. Es demasiado complejo la manera en la que lo estaba haciendo, tienes razon.

Comment: @LuchoK Python es muy expresivo, es decir, que con poco código consigues expresar algoritmos complejos, gracias a todo lo que ya trae incorporado en el lenguaje. Compensa hacer algún tutorial para aprenderlo, aunque leer código escrito por otros es también una buena forma de ir descubriendo el "estilo pythónico"